# YN 622n for nikon D3300 for HSS

Tags: nikon

i have Nikon D3300 which does not support HSS.

by using YN-622n and a speed light, will it make the camera to do HSS??

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You need a camera that supports HSS (called Auto FP mode in Nikon nomenclature).